# What is EXTRN in Intel-syntax assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, cl, intel-syntax

x86 CPU: MSVC (2010)

What does `EXTRN   _printf:PROC` means in code bellow and why after "`:`" we use some "`PROC`" directive instead of "`near`" or "`far`"?

```
CONST   SEGMENT 
$SG3830 DB     'hello, world', 0AH, 00H 
CONST   ENDS 
PUBLIC  _main 
EXTRN   _printf:PROC  <- what is this funct?!
_TEXT   SEGMENT 
_main   PROC 
        push   ebp 
        mov    ebp,    esp 
        push   OFFSET  $SG3830 
        call   _printf 
        add    esp,    4 
        xor    eax,    eax 
        pop    ebp 
        ret    0 
_main   ENDP 
_TEXT   ENDS
```

Comment: Have you read the assembler's manual?  What did it say?  If you want further help, I need to know which specific assembler you are programming with.

Comment: @fuz Just edited question if you will. Actually I thought it's same for any Intel-based compiler, so didn't mention.

Comment: @Deno Assemblers are not the same things as compilers.  Make sure to not confuse them.  Note that there are many assemblers using an Intel-like syntax.  One of them is MASM, the assembler shipped with MSVC.  There are other popular assemblers like nasm, fasm, and yasm.

Comment: Thanks 4 that info as well. I'll consider how to qualify assemblers before asking next time. Untill now was wondering why people don't understand.. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears you are reading Reverse Engineering for Beginners by Dennis Yurichev. In 32-bit FLAT model everything is considered a NEAR pointer (within the 4Gib address space). The concept of NEAR/FAR applied to things like the segmented address model of DOS programs. The code you are looking is the assembly code from the MSVC compiler(CL) for a 32-bit Windows console program.

[`EXTRN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/extern-masm?view=vs-2019) just means there is external linkage to a symbol that is a function/**PROC**edure in some other module/library/object that will eventually be linked to. Without the EXTRN directive the `call _printf` would produce an error since the `_printf` function is not defined in the current assembly file.